# Aspnet.core - Docker File creating anonymous images

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

When using the docker file template provided by Visual Studio 2017, I realize that every time I create the image of my application, two other images are always created, instead of being reused. Why does this occur?

[image]

Comment: What is the command to build images and what is project version? I made a test with `docker build -f "C:\Users\xx\source\repos\WebApplication15\Dockerfile" -t webapplication15:dev1 --target base  --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" "C:\Users\xx\source\repos"`, it reused the cache. For `anonymous images`, it will be created when there is error while building and when using with multi-stage. What is your dockerfile?

Comment: I'm using command docker build -t ltstore .

Comment: FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app


FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["LtStore/*.*", "LtStore/"]
COPY ["LtStore.Core/LtStore.Core.csproj", "LtStore.Core/"]
RUN dotnet restore "LtStore/LtStore.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/LtStore"
RUN dotnet build "LtStore.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "LtStore.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "LtStore.dll"]

Comment: Try to specify `--target base`, `base` is the stage.

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile template from Visual Studio 2017 uses intermediate images while building. Like one image is used as a base image and intermediate containers images are used to build and publish the output into your base image. After that happens the final image is given a tag. While others remain without any repository name and tag.

Answer (score -1):

you can build the new images with `--cache-from` switch to reuse and speed up build process or `--rm` for removing intermediate and dangling images
for more information about build:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Comment: the intermediate containers are being removed, but the images are not.

Comment: I’m using docker rmi $(docker images -a -q) in crontab for removing unused images.